# Cypress get text from list of elements

Tags: cypress

I have seen a bunch of people asking a similar question, but the answers are not working for me.

Here is the html:

```
<tr role="row" aria-rowindex="2" class=""><td aria-colindex="1" role="cell" class=""><div class="d-flex">
          Investor1
        </div></td><td aria-colindex="2" role="cell" class="">
        Product1
      </td><td aria-colindex="3" role="cell" class="mr-0 pr-0 text-right"><button class="ml-auto minus-icon mr-1"></button></td></tr>
<tr role="row" aria-rowindex="2" class=""><td aria-colindex="1" role="cell" class=""><div class="d-flex">
          Investor1
        </div></td><td aria-colindex="2" role="cell" class="">
        Product2
      </td><td aria-colindex="3" role="cell" class="mr-0 pr-0 text-right"><button class="ml-auto minus-icon mr-1"></button></td></tr>
<tr role="row" aria-rowindex="2" class=""><td aria-colindex="1" role="cell" class=""><div class="d-flex">
          Investor2
        </div></td><td aria-colindex="2" role="cell" class="">
        Product1
      </td><td aria-colindex="3" role="cell" class="mr-0 pr-0 text-right"><button class="ml-auto minus-icon mr-1"></button></td></tr>
```

I need to get the list of products for an specific investor and return it, since I use this in multiple places, I was trying to make a method that I could call to:

- first check if a product for a specific investor was already added
- add it if not and verify it's now present.

Here is my method code:

```
/**
     * Returns a list of products for the investor passed
     * @param {string} investor 
     * @return {array} list of products
     */
    getListOfProductsAlreadyPresent(investor) {
        this.elements.sourceProductTableProduct().filter(`:contains(${investor})`).as('listForInvestor');
        cy.get('@listForInvestor').then(($els) => {
            return (Cypress.$.makeArray($els).map((element) => {
                cy.wrap(element).parent('td').next('td').invoke('text');
            })
            );
        });
```

And the call to the method:

```
 this.getListOfProductsAlreadyPresent(investor).as('productList');
 cy.wrap('@productList').then((list) => {
     if (!list.includes(sourceProduct)) {
        this.setSourceProductIfNotPresent(investor, sourceProduct, true);
     }
});
```

and after the product gets added:

```
this.getListOfProductsAlreadyPresent(investor).as('productList');
cy.wrap('@productList').then((list) => {
     if (!list.includes(sourceProduct)) {
        throw new Error(`Source product ${sourceProduct} did not get added successfully for investor ${investor}`);
     }
});
```

My code above doesn't work. It would be very easy to do this with Xpath, since one Xpath would get the list of elements, but I'd rather not have to use the xpath module unless that's the only solution.
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I can give you a cleaner example

The problem HTML can be represented by this. I've added some white-space around the text, as that seems to be an issue for you as well.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>

      one
    
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      
      two
    
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can retrieve the rows and apply a filter based on the `:contains` pseudo-selector.

If the text is "three" (not in the HTML), `found` is false.

```js
cy.get('tr').then($rows => {
  const result = $rows.filter(':contains(three)')
  const found = !!result.length
  expect(found).to.eq(false)
})
```

If the text is "two" (which is in the HTML), `found` is true.

```js
cy.get('tr').then($rows => {
  const result = $rows.filter(':contains(two)')
  const found = !!result.length
  expect(found).to.eq(true)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up implementing it as follow for both cases, which works, but is there a way to make a method out of it so I don't have to repeat the code twice?

```
this.elements.sourceProductTableInvestorProduct().then(($els) => {
            let found = false;
            for (const element of $els) {
                const innerText = `${element.innerText.split(/\r?\n/)[0].trim()} ${element.innerText.split(/\r?\n/)[1].trim()}`;
                cy.log(`InnerText: ${innerText} and investor: ${investor} and product: ${sourceProduct}`);
                if (innerText.includes(investor) && innerText.includes(sourceProduct)) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                ....
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do not use an answer to ask a follow-on question. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)